# Copying the same data in sql, from source table to target table using merge is read as different data but it is the same json source parsed in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a JSON String that I parsed out to fit my requirement, no problem doing it and it comes as I want it and I load that to my source table then I use merge to load my target table. this JSON string hasn't been changed for my source table it parse and truncate and load to my source table every time I run the procedure, but the issue is my merge read it as a different data so it loads it to my target table instead it should be read as the same and should not be load to my target. why is this happening? my target and source don't have any PK or Identity. I am using SQL Server 2017.
**Update:-** I was able to do what I want using Lookup Transformation in SSIS. 
But why when I run the procedure my merge read it as a new data since the JSON string hasn't been changed. help me understand this, please. Thank you

here is a JSon String extracted from facebook.

> [{"value":75,"end_time":"2019-08-06T03:00:00-04:00"},{"value":6,"end_time":"2019-08-07T03:00:00-04:00"},{"value":5,"end_time":"2019-08-08T03:00:00-04:00"},{"value":3,"end_time":"2019-08-09T03:00:00-04:00"},{"value":50,"end_time":"2019-08-10T03:00:00-04:00"}]

I have parsed out to this.

```
value       EndTime
75          2019-08-06
6           2019-08-07
5           2019-08-08
3           2019-08-09
50          2019-08-10
```

Now this is in my Source table

every time I run my proc, it calls the same metric to API and gets the JSON string above.

here my merge

```
MERGE targetTable T
    USING
        (
            SELECT   
                    VALUE
                    ,EndDate

            FROM SourceTable S

        ) s
        ON
        (                                       
                    S.EndDate   = T.EndDate     
        )

    WHEN MATCHED AND
        (                   
                        ISNULL(S.VALUE,'')  <> ISNULL(T.VALUE,'')                               
        )
    THEN UPDATE
        SET                             
                    T.VALUE                 = S.VALUE                                       

    WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT VALUES
        (                                                
                             S.VALUE                            
                            ,S.EndDate                  

        );
```

Comment: Sample data and expected output will help

Comment: do u know how `Merge` works ? between source and target.We need to see a bit of your sp to exactly understand what you are doing

Comment: MERGE targetTable T
 USING
  (
   SELECT  
     VALUE
     ,EndDate
     
   FROM SourceTable S
   
  ) s
  ON
  (          
     S.EndDate = T.EndDate  
  )

 WHEN MATCHED AND
  (     
      ISNULL(S.VALUE,'') <> ISNULL(T.VALUE,'')        
  )
 THEN UPDATE
  SET        
     T.VALUE     = S.VALUE          

 WHEN NOT MATCHED
 THEN INSERT VALUES
  (             
        S.VALUE       
       ,S.EndDate     
       
  );